# Что за файлы с суффиксом template?

Tags: angular2, dart

Решил интереса ради поковырять Angular Dart, открыл Tour of Heroes и что-то не понимаю, откуда в главном модуле берутся файлы с суффиксом `template`.

[Например](https://github.com/angular-examples/toh-6/blob/master/web/main.dart):

```
import 'package:angular_tour_of_heroes/app_component.template.dart' as ng;
import 'main.template.dart' as self;
```

Облазил всю директорию на гитхабе и не нашел этих файлов...

В тоже время, у меня Visual Studio Code подсвечивает все красным.

Что за магия?

Comment: https://github.com/angular-examples/toh-6/blob/master/lib/app_component.dart

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял template-файлы появляются после первого билда.

После того как приложение собралось краснота пропала.